# Full Width Image with Cropped Height in Xamarin.Forms ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm loading a list of items and I'm trying to lay out the image (from a URL) as the background with full width and the height cropped if necessary, and overlay some text and images on top. I can't get the image to expand to the full width and height no matter what I do. I've tried about everything I can think of but here's how the code looks at this point:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="mainStack" Orientation="Vertical">
  <Label x:Name="errorMsg" IsVisible="False" />
  <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="False" IsVisible="False" x:Name="activityIndicator" />
  <ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" Refreshing="OnRefreshItems" ItemSelected="LoadDetails" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20" RowHeight="280">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <AbsoluteLayout HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" />
              <Image Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="opacity.png" />
              <Image Source="favorite.png" HeightRequest="50" />
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,.3,.3" >
                <Image Source="shareList.png" HeightRequest="30" />
                <Image Source="shareList.png" HeightRequest="30" />
              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1,.7,.8,.1">
                <Label Text="{Binding StartFormatted}"  TextColor="#ffffff" Style="{StaticResource dateList}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#ffffff" Style="{StaticResource h1Style}" />
              </StackLayout>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "image to expand to the full width and height". Do you mean for full screen or original image size? It seems you limit your cell height by 200. Is image has bigger height or smaller than 200 (actually what is the image size)? What sizes of the rest of images - opacity,favorite and shareList. I would like to reproduce the problem, so screenshot and possibly sample project code (or just images so I don't have to recreate them) will be good. But sample project will save a lot of time if I have code behind with all bindings defined.

Comment: Expand tot he full width and height of the container. I was able to get it to work, don't love the solution so if there's a better option I'd love to hear it. Images are being uploaded by users have no control over the original image size, needs to work regardless of the original image size. Really looking for an equivalent of what would be width=100% on the web, and the image being centered vertically.

Comment: What about sample project with all images and bindings?